# Which DBpedia dataset dump contains dbpedia ontology labels?

Tags: dbpedia, virtuoso

My aim is to be able to perform the following kind of queries within Virtuoso, without being dependent on whether DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint is currently up or not:

```
SELECT ?label WHERE {
 ?prop rdfs:domain <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SpaceMission> .
 ?prop rdfs:label ?label .
 FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en') 
}
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to be able to identify the correct data set to download that would also include the labels of these properties. I currently have the mapping-based properties installed: http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.9/en/mappingbased_properties_en.nt.bz2 and I do get the properties but there are no property labels there.

Is there another installation I am missing or is the only way to query that data from DBpedia's live endpoint?

Comment: What do you mean by "without being dependent on whether DBpedia's SPARQL endpoint is currently up or not"?

Comment: The other day it was down for a few hours and I cannot risk that happening, hence i prefer not having to use SERVICE calls where pospible

Comment: So, you mean, you want to install DBpedia locally and query it, with virtuoso (locally); am I correctly understand you?

Comment: And I did figure already out that I was missing the DBpedia ontology. Now I have labels too.